# How do I get the current cookie / session ID from a HttpResponseMessage?

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5, system.net.httpwebrequest

I try to use the new .net 4.5 HttpClient from System.net.http.

I set-up my client like this

```
CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
         HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
         {
             CookieContainer = cookieJar,
             AllowAutoRedirect = true
         };
         handler.UseCookies = true;
         handler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

         HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler as HttpMessageHandler);
```

then I do a `client.GetAsync(url)`

now I am inspecting the response and try to get the cookie / session values for a following post.

I try to test a login scenario of an existing page via code...

How do I get the cookie information in a response? Or do I walk on a wrong path here?
Any explanation would be fantastic...

Answer (score 3):

The cookie exists in the form of a header that is the instruction to create the cookie on the client. Those headers have the form of "Set-Cookie" as the actual header, with the value of "CookieTitle={form encoded value}". Getting that cookie looks like this:

```
var cookieTitle = "MyCookieTitle";

var response = ... // get response object
var cookie = response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie").First(x => x.StartsWith(cookieTitle));
```

That gets you the raw string of the header, which will look like this:

```
CookieTitle=this+is+the+value+of+the+cookie
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the 'Set-Cookie' header of the HTTP response.

Comment: How do I access the property? response.Headers is of type HttpResponseHeaders but does not contain a method or property Set-Cookie' could you please get more in details...

Comment: The response type is HttpResponseHeaders. Apart from some standard properties, you can try accessing the key-value pairs via TryGetValues() method. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the cookies and re-specify them for your next POST.  The HttpClient will take care of doing that for you.

As long as the URL that you are POSTing to is within the path that was defined by the cookie then the cookie will automatically be resent with the request.

For example, if you create your cookie like this,

```
 public class CookieController : ApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage Get() {
            var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
            var cookieHeaderValues = new List<CookieHeaderValue>();
            cookieHeaderValues.Add(new CookieHeaderValue("foo","bar") 
                                         {Domain = "myhost",Path = "/"});
            httpResponseMessage.Headers.AddCookies(cookieHeaderValues);
            return  httpResponseMessage;
        }
    }
```

Any request to any URL below `http://myhost/`  will automatically be sent this cookie.